# deleting selected lines from data file

Tags: awk

This question is continuation from my earlier post titled "selecting digits from regular expression".

Below is the sample data as posted in the earlier post.

```
          DONOR         ACCEPTORH      ACCEPTOR           
    atom#  res@atom   atom#  res@atom atom#  res@atom %occupied  distance       angle        
  |  4726   59@O12 |  1487    19@H12  1486    19@O12 |  85.66  2.819 ( 0.18)  21.85 (12.11)        
  |  1499   19@O15 |  1730    22@H12  1729    22@O12 |  83.15  3.190 ( 0.31)  22.36 (12.73)        
  |  1216   16@O22 |  1460    19@H22  1459    19@O22 |  75.74  2.757 ( 0.14)  24.55 (13.66)        
  |  4232   53@O25 |  4143    52@H24  4142    52@O24 |  74.35  2.916 ( 0.25)  28.27 (13.26)        
  |  3683   46@O16 |  4163    52@H13  4162    52@O13 |  73.78  2.963 ( 0.29)  23.65 (14.14)        
  |  4162   52@O13 |  4079    51@H12  4078    51@O12 |  73.68  2.841 ( 0.19)  21.25 (11.87)        
  |  3764   47@O16 |  3825    48@H26  3824    48@O26 |  70.52  2.973 ( 0.28)  26.88 (13.14)        
  .
  .
  The lines goes few thousands.
```

I tired Fredirk's code and it works fine for selecting the lines. Well, now I would like to extend this idea to my real problem.

The $3 (3rd field) and $6 (6th field) in my data file represent "number-molecule"  which has arrangement as below:

```
   1    2   3   4   5   6   7       8

   9    10  11  12  13  14  15      16
  17    18  19  20  21  22  23      24
  25    26  27  28  29  30  31      32
  33    34  35  36  37  38  39      40
  41    42  43  44  45  46  47      48
  49    50  51  52  53  54  55      56

  57    58  59  60  61  62  63      64
```

Any pairs made from above numbers actually represents pairs in the 3rd and 6th field of each line in the data file.

What I want is to select the pairs made only by numbers which arranged at the outer most lines of the above ordering.

```
 In short, ANY PAIRS made by only the numbers  (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8   57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64   1 9 17 25 33 41 49 57   8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64) are need to be deleted.
```

I have no idea how to write loop in awk code to select those pairs and delete the lines straight away.

I wish to say many thanks in advance.

Comment: BEGIN {
  i=0
  for (n=1; n<=8; n++) set[i++] = n;
  for (n=57; n<=64; n++) set[i++] = n;
  for (n=9; n<=49; n+=8) {set[i++] = n; set[i++] = n+7}
}

/^|/{
    split($3, a, "@")
    split($6, b, "@")

 if ( ($3 in set) && ($6 in set) ) print

    #if(a[1] >= 1 && a[1] <= 8 && b[1] >=1 && b[1] <= 8) print
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to hold the set of numbers. Define it in the BEGIN block

```
BEGIN {
  i=0
  for (n=1; n<=8; n++) set[i++] = n
  for (n=57; n<=64; n++) set[i++] = n
  for (n=9; n<=49; n+=8) {set[i++] = n; set[i++] = n+7}
}
```

Then, check that $3 and $6 are both in (or not in) the set:

```
($3 in set) && ($6 in set) {next}
```

Comment: I have tried to run as the code here. But I dont get error neither  answer.     BEGIN {
  i=0
  for (n=1; n<=8; n++) set[i++] = n;
  for (n=57; n<=64; n++) set[i++] = n;
  for (n=9; n<=49; n+=8) {set[i++] = n; set[i++] = n+7}
}

/^|/{
    split($3, a, "@")
    split($6, b, "@")

 if ( ($3 in set) && ($6 in set) ) print

    #if(a[1] >= 1 && a[1] <= 8 && b[1] >=1 && b[1] <= 8) print
}

Comment: well obviously you don't want to use $3 and $6, you want to use a[1] and b[1]. Don't expect me to go hunting for your old questions to get all the details: you can't even be bothered to provide a link.

Comment: Sorry for the missing link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303821/selecting-digits-from-regular-expression