# deleting selected lines from data file-part2

Tags: awk

This is following previous discussion: ( [deleting selected lines from data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343411/deleting-selected-lines-from-data-file))

I have tried follow the idea addressed by Fredirk and  Glenn Jackman and I come out with the code as below to only print the lines if the pair of numbers are matching specific creteria.

When I execute the code, there is output but it prints all the lines instead only the specific ones.

```
 #!/usr/bin/awk -f

 BEGIN  {
   i=0
   for (n=1; n<=8; n++) set[i++] = n;
   for (n=57; n<=64; n++) set[i++] = n;
   for (n=9; n<=49; n+=8) {set[i++] = n; set[i++] = n+7};
    }


 /^|/{
     split($3, res1, "@"); split($6, res2, "@"); #print res1[1], res2[1]

     if ( (res1[1] in set) == (res2[1] in set) ); 

     {
       print;
       next;

     }

 }
```

Could anyone help to find any bug if there is one? I can figure out why it is not getting.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a stray semi-colon after the `if` command. You do nothing if that condition is true. And then you print each line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have deleted the semicolon and I changed the '==' to '&&'. This time I get some answers but not as I wanted. I want both numbers, ( res1[1] and res2[1] ) from array "set" alone and if this condition occur, THAT particular line shall be DELETED. I give the code for your consideration. Thank you. #!/usr/bin/awk -f
 BEGIN {
 i=0
 for(n=1; n<=8; n++) set[i++] = n;
 for(n=57; n<=64; n++) set[i++] = n;
 for(n=9; n<=49; n+=8) {set[i++] = n; set[i++] = n+7}; }
 ($1=="|"){
split($3, res1, "@"); split($6, res2, "@");
if ((res1[1] in set) && (res2[1] in set))  
{ print; next; }
}

Comment: If you want the line deleted, why are you printing it?

Comment: Printing just want to confirm that it is selecting the right lines which supposed to delete. ( I am newbie in programming ). Thank you